# Set Up Continuous Integration From VSO to Azure, but Website does not deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have an azure website that I have successfully linked to a team project in VSO. When I go to the "deployments" tab of this site in azure management, it says:

> The team project is linked. Visual Studio Online will build and deploy
>   your project to Windows Azure on your next check-in.

Below, it gives options to check in from VS2012 or 2010.  I am using VS 2013.

In VS, I am able to check in changes and see those changes building in the cloud in the team explorer.  My expectation is that after the changes build, they should be auto deployed to the website.  This is not happening. I have made several checkins, and none are deployed to the website.  It's probably that I have something configured incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to debug this.

In the Build Settings I am using the TFvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml build process template. One thing I did notice is that the under the Deployment Parameters, I noticed that Windows Azure Deployment Environment is empty, but if I try to populate that I'm not sure what to enter for "Web site name" or "Webspace" under the web site radio buttom.

I have followed instructions on these websites to no avail:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-584
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/deploy-to-azure-vs.aspx

How can I check on the status of the deployment?  How can I make sure that the project/solution is correctly configured to deploy/publish and not just build?

Some additional info:
To set up the continuous deploy, I goto azure management portal, click websites, open the website in question. Click the Deployments tab. It says "The team project is linked, Visual studio online will build and deploy your project to Windows Azure on your next check in". Under YOUR SERVER is lists the correct visual studio online URL for my source project (https://------.visualstudio.com). This is my first time trying CD. It has not successfully deployed yet, but the build is working. Every time I check in changes, a cloud build is triggered and it is successful.

I'm new to this, so I am likely making some unfounded assumption, but after going through the instructions multiple times I'm not sure what I can be missing.

Thank you!

Comment: `Website name` is the name of the website, e.g. `http://<whatever>.azurewebsites.net`. `Webspace` is just the region the site is in, e.g. `West US`.

Answer (score 0):

l19 has the right idea in the comment responding to my post. I needed to specify a Windows Azure Deployment Environment.  The website name is the name of the website.  Webspace is a bit trickier, and unfortunately the documentation link in visual studio redirects to a not found page. This has to be precise (e.g., "west us" won't work).  I was able to figure out the proper string by creating a new project from azure and associating it with vso from the start. In this case, the build definition was correctly configured. I opened the Windows Azure Deployment Environment and saw that the webspace was set to "eastuswebspace", so I used the same string in my real build definition and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! I faced the same problem and I was able to solve by adding the "eastuswebspace" also!